# A Python Window-services Library

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-services

Does anybody could help or know for using/working with windows services python library ?
I tried pywinservicemanager but didn't help .

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1115336/Using-Python-to-Make-a-Windows-Service    check this out

Comment: Atlast I found the 'psutil' library, It has lots of functions that can call like the service name, process id, status of the services - running, stopped.